# Number of Imported Documents using mongoimport does not match documents in database

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am using Heroku with `mongolab` add-on, and using `mongoimport` to import documents.

When I run the command, `mongoimport` works and tells me it imported 9479 documents, which is correct. However, when I check the database, there are only 5000 documents. (It seems to switch between 4999 or 5000). I tried the operation multiple times to the same results.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you hit mongolab's db size limit?

Comment: no, because if I repeat the command without first deleting all 5000 documents, I end up with 10,000 documents in the database -- so I don't think the size limit is the issue.